# How to convert all elements in list from datetime to date?

Tags: python

```
[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 23, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 0, 0)]
```

to

```
[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 23, 0, 0).date(), datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 0, 0).date()]
```

so I can have this:

```
[datetime.date(2015, 6, 23), datetime.date(2015, 6, 24)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using a list comprehension.

```
my_date_list = [d.date() for d in my_datetime_list]
```

[List Comprehension Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke the `date` method on each `datetime` object within a list comprehension. If your list of `datetime` objects was named `l`, then for example you could do the following

```
>>> [i.date() for i in l]
[datetime.date(2015, 6, 23), datetime.date(2015, 6, 24)]
```

Comment: I am really appreciated for your answer but @ssundarraj was a few seconds quicker. I wish I could accept both answers.

Comment: No worries :) It is a [known phenomenon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)